# What is the difference between "make clean" and "make clobber"?

Tags: makefile

Can anyone tell me the differences between "make clean" and "make clobber"? I searched but didn't find a useful answer.

Comment: As the answer below states there are some [conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Standard-Targets), but to be certain you need to read the build documentation of the project you're building, or failing that look at the makefile itself.

Comment: @user657267 Those are useful comments -- I'll include them in my answer if you don't mind. (Submit a rollback edit if you disapprove.)

Comment: "clobber" used to be widely-used, before the GNU convention took hold in the mid-1990s.  In the latter, "distclean" is closest.

Comment: Since Guido came and clarified directly, it seems like you should probably change the accepted answer to this post when you next return to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of these terms has a firmly established meaning. The Makefile author creates targets and gives them human-readable names; [conventionally,](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Standard-Targets) `clean` means to remove things from a previous build, while `clobber` means to forcibly overwrite some previous results. The latter is less commonly seen or necessary.

In each case, for each Makefile, you should read any accompanying build documentation, or examine the `Makefile` and understand what it does, or, perhaps as a last resort, ask the author.

Answer (score 1):

In the CPython project, `make clean` removes intermediate results like `.o` files, `make clobber` also removes end results like the `python` (or `python.exe`, on Mac) executable itself, while `make distclean` attempts to remove even the `Makefile` (and other build infrastructure) itself. After the latter, you'd need to re-run `./configure`.

The intention of `make clean` is to simply force recompilation. The intention of `make clobber` is to also clean up (space-intensive) build products. The intention of `make distclean` is to produce a source tree that can be tarred up for distribution.

In practice each of these is somewhat flawed, and if you *truly* wanted to remove all build artifacts, you'd probably be best off with a clean git clone.

Python's own documentation appears to no longer recommend `make clobber`, and only describes `make clean` and `make distclean`.